# Error al iniciar MySQL en XAMPP

Tags: mysql, xampp

He instalado XAMPP en un equipo WINDOWS, pero me da error al iniciarlo.

Ya desinstalé e instalé dos veces, pero el error me sigue apareciendo.
Abrí el `logdata` y esto es lo que me aparece:

> 2015-11-10 15:26:56 10fc InnoDB: Warning: Using
>   innodb_additional_mem_pool_size is DEPRECATED. This option may be
>   removed in future releases, together with the option
>   innodb_use_sys_malloc and with the InnoDB's internal memory allocator.
>   2015-11-10 15:26:56 4348 [Note] InnoDB: Using mutexes to ref count
>   buffer pool pages 2015-11-10 15:26:56 4348 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB
>   memory heap is disabled 2015-11-10 15:26:56 4348 [Note] InnoDB:
>   Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions 2015-11-10
>   15:26:56 4348 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used 2015-11-10
>   15:26:56 4348 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
>   2015-11-10 15:26:56 4348 [Note] InnoDB: Not using CPU crc32
>   instructions 2015-11-10 15:26:56 4348 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing
>   buffer pool, size = 16.0M 2015-11-10 15:26:56 4348 [Note] InnoDB:
>   Completed initialization of buffer pool 2015-11-10 15:26:56 4348
>   [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda. 2015-11-10
>   15:26:57 4348 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
>   2015-11-10 15:26:57 4348 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
>   2015-11-10 15:26:57 4348 [Note] InnoDB:  Percona XtraDB
>   (http://www.percona.com) 5.6.26-74.0 started; log sequence number
>   1835027 2015-11-10 15:26:57 6140 [Note] InnoDB: Dumping buffer pool(s)
>   not yet started 2015-11-10 15:26:57 4348 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is
>   disabled. 2015-11-10 15:26:57 4348 [Note] Server socket created on IP:
>   '::'. 2015-11-10 15:26:57 4348 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
>   2015-11-10 15:26:57 4348 [Note] C:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe: ready
>   for connections. Version: '10.1.8-MariaDB'  socket: ''  port: 3306 
>   mariadb.org binary distribution 2015-11-10 15:27:11 5152 [Note]
>   C:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe: Normal shutdown
>
> 2015-11-10 15:27:11 5152 [Note] Event Scheduler: Purging the queue. 0
>   events 2015-11-10 15:27:11 5732 [Note] InnoDB: FTS optimize thread
>   exiting. 2015-11-10 15:27:11 5152 [Note] InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
>   2015-11-10 15:27:13 5152 [Note] InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log
>   sequence number 1835037 2015-11-10 15:27:13 5152 [Note]
>   C:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe: Shutdown complete
>
> 2018-09-06 14:01:03 16b4 InnoDB: Warning: Using
>   innodb_additional_mem_pool_size is DEPRECATED. This option may be
>   removed in future releases, together with the option
>   innodb_use_sys_malloc and with the InnoDB's internal memory allocator.
>   2018-09-06 14:01:03 5812 [Note] InnoDB:
>   innodb_empty_free_list_algorithm has been changed to legacy because of
>   small buffer pool size. In order to use backoff, increase buffer pool
>   at least up to 20MB.
>
> 2018-09-06 14:01:03 5812 [Note] InnoDB: Using mutexes to ref count
>   buffer pool pages 2018-09-06 14:01:03 5812 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB
>   memory heap is disabled 2018-09-06 14:01:03 5812 [Note] InnoDB:
>   Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions 2018-09-06
>   14:01:03 5812 [Note] InnoDB: _mm_lfence() and _mm_sfence() are used
>   for memory barrier 2018-09-06 14:01:03 5812 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed
>   tables use zlib 1.2.3 2018-09-06 14:01:03 5812 [Note] InnoDB: Using
>   generic crc32 instructions 2018-09-06 14:01:03 5812 [Note] InnoDB:
>   Initializing buffer pool, size = 16.0M 2018-09-06 14:01:03 5812 [Note]
>   InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool 2018-09-06 14:01:04
>   5812 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
>   2018-09-06 14:01:04 5812 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are
>   active. 2018-09-06 14:01:04 5812 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to
>   start 2018-09-06 14:01:04 5812 [Note] InnoDB:  Percona XtraDB
>   (http://www.percona.com) 5.6.38-83.0 started; log sequence number
>   1835037 2018-09-06 14:01:04 7352 [Note] InnoDB: Dumping buffer pool(s)
>   not yet started 2018-09-06 14:01:04 5812 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is
>   disabled. 2018-09-06 14:01:04 5812 [Note] Server socket created on IP:
>   '::'. 2018-09-06 14:01:04 5812 [ERROR] Can't start server: Bind on
>   TCP/IP port. Got error: 10048: Only one usage of each socket address
>   (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted.
>
> 2018-09-06 14:01:04 5812 [ERROR] Do you already have another mysqld
>   server running on port: 3306 ? 2018-09-06 14:01:04 5812 [ERROR]
>   Aborting

En la máquina hay otra instancia, pero de una aplicación que se conecta a una base de datos MySQL. Pero no puedo desinstalarla, entonces ¿cómo cambio el puerto de MySQL XAMPP o qué debo hacer?

¿Alguien que haya experimentado un problema similar?

Comment: Al final de esa novela, dice "Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted." y "Do you already have another mysqld server running on port: 3306". Está diciendo que el puerto 3306 está actualmente en uso por algún otro sistema en ese equipo. Verifica si tienes otra instancia de mysql o mariadb corriendo.

Comment: Si hay otra instancia, pero una aplicacion que se conecta a una BDD MySQL. Pero no puedo desinstalarla, entonces como cambio el puerto de MySQL XAMPP o que debo hacer.

Comment: @JoseDanielSolis , ¿solucionaste el problema?

Comment: @OscarGarcia
Disculpa, por dejar tanto tiempo el tema sin contestar.
Amigo, no puedo ver la instancia instalada de MySQL, creo es un conector porque no hay ninguna base de datos allí. Solo esta la aplicación (Software Externo) instalado.

DS

Comment: ¿Podrías definir qué es para ti un conector? ¿Y a qué te refieres con que "Sólo está la aplicación (software externo)"?

Comment: @OscarGarcia

Connector un Driver ejemplo: Connector/NET 8.0.12

El Software Externo, es el que comente al inicio de la pregunta, es una aplicación que se conecta a la base de datos (MySQL) y no se en que lenguaje este desarrollado (Java. Net, C# etc) 

Yo necesito instalar XAMPP, en ese equipo para usarlo como servidor.

DS

Comment: Ese "software externo" se conecta a un MySQL. ¿Dónde está ese MySQL? ¿En la misma máquina o en el exterior?

Comment: @OscarGarcia
MySQL esta en el exterior, servidor externo.

DS

Comment: Entoces no tiene sentido que el puerto esté en uso. En ese caso, te puedo guiar para localizar el proceso que ocupa el puerto que debería usar el MySQL de xampp y deshabilitar el servicio asociado para que puedas completar la instalación. ¿Puedes hacer uso del chat de stackoverflow o usamos otro método de comunicación?

Comment: tenia el mismo problema con una instalacion nueva de xampp, siguiendo el consejo de Oscar busque mysql en el buscador de windows y aparecion "mySql stop" le di click ahi y paro el proceso, despues pude concetarme a 3306 sin problemas

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Cuando tienes una instalación previa de MySQL en la misma máquina que no puedes deinstalarla porque a ella acceden otras aplicaciones, debes seguir el siguiente procedimiento para conseguir instalar ambas con diferentes puertos:

- Renombrar el servicio MySQL original (para evitar ser sobreescrito por XAMPP) navegando en el registro `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services` buscando la subclave con el nombre `MySQL`, `MySQL server` o similar. Pulsar el botón derecho y `Renombrar` para cambiar el nombre a `MySQL_original` por poner un ejemplo. Puedes hacer una copia de seguridad de la rama antes de hacer los cambios.
- Comprobar en `services.msc` que el servicio ha cambiado correctamente de nombre y que arranca correctamente tras reiniciar la máquina.
- Antes de instalar XAMPP parar el servicio MySQL original (temporalmente, sólo durante el proceso de instalación de XAMPP).
- Realizar la instalación de XAMPP.
- Arrancar el panel de control de XAMPP como administrador (`XAMPP` > `XAMPP Control Panel` pulsando el botón derecho y `Ejecutar como administrador`).
- Pulsar el botón `Config` de la fila correspondiente a `MySQL`.
- En el archivo `my.cnf` abierto buscar bajo la etiqueta `[mysqld]` el parámetro `port  = 3306` para cambiarlo por cualquier otro puerto, por ejemplo `port = 3307`.
- Reiniciar el servicio pulsando en `Stop` y luego en `Start` en el panel de control de XAMPP o en `services.msc`.
- Arrancar el servicio MySQL original y comprobar que éste arranca correctamente.
- Reiniciar la máquina para comprobar que los cambios se mantienen tras el reinicio sin conflicto alguno.

Ahora podrás conectar a ambas instancias por los siguientes puertos:

- 3306: MySQL original
- 3307: MySQL instalado por XAMPP

Answer (score -1):

Busque en administrador de tareas algun programa que pudiera estar ocupando el mismo puerto, en mi caso encontré un programa corriendo en segundo plano que decia mysql cuando supuestamente ninguno debería estar corriendo, entonces finalice esa tarea y corrí mi XAMPP con MySQL y funcionó.